# Dart analyzer: Get type of initial value of a field

Tags: dart, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, dart-analyzer

How can I get the type of an initial value expression of a field using [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/)'s [analyzer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) API?

```
class MyClass {
  var prop = <initial value expression>;
}
```

If initial value expression is for example `'text'`, I'd like to get `String`. If it is a function call, I'd like to get the return type of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting a fully resolved AST structure, ask the `Expression` representing the initial value expression for it's `staticType`. That will return the `DartType` representing the static type.

It's possible for type inference to produce a more specialized type, which you can access using `propagatedType`. (And if you don't care which type you get, you can use `bestType`.